# Grouping same values in one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am new to pandas. I am having columns payment1 payment2,payment3,payment4,payment5,payment6 total 6 columns in data frame .now these columns contains value 5(credit card)  and 10(cash).based on this input I want to create new columns payment(credit) in which all 5 comes in one columns and all 10 comes in another column payment(cash)
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAatI.png)

output should be [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr7HL.png)

```
payment(creadit) payment(cash)
5                   10
5                   10 
                    10
5                   10
5
5                   10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- generated data that has same input shape as your image
- functionally it's a conditional sum across the row axis
- this can be coded as `r.eq(n).sum()*n`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'payment1': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
 'payment2': [10, 5, '', 5, '', '', 5, '', 5, ''],
 'payment3': ['', '', 10, '', 10, 10, '', 10, '', ''],
 'payment4': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
 'payment5': ['', '', '', 10, '', '', '', 5, '', ''],
 'payment6': ['', '', '', '', 5, '', '', '', '', 5]})

df = df.assign(**{"payment(creadit)":df.apply(lambda r: r.eq(10).sum()*10, axis=1),
            "payment(cash)":df.apply(lambda r: r.eq(5).sum()*5, axis=1)}).replace({0:""})
```

#### output

|  | payment1 | payment2 | payment3 | payment4 | payment5 | payment6 | payment(creadit) | payment(cash) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | 10 |  |  |  |  | 10 |  |
| 1 |  | 5 |  |  |  |  |  | 5 |
| 2 |  |  | 10 |  |  |  | 10 |  |
| 3 |  | 5 |  |  | 10 |  | 10 | 5 |
| 4 |  |  | 10 |  |  | 5 | 10 | 5 |
| 5 |  |  | 10 |  |  |  | 10 |  |
| 6 |  | 5 |  |  |  |  |  | 5 |
| 7 |  |  | 10 |  | 5 |  | 10 | 5 |
| 8 |  | 5 |  |  |  |  |  | 5 |
| 9 |  |  |  |  |  | 5 |  | 5 |

Comment: Thanks for solution.but if you check input then in that for each row value 10 or 5 comes in one time only and we need to separate out 10 and 5 instread of doing sum.

Comment: It will work for the condition you note.  It you provide your input data as text rather than unusable image I will demonstrate

Comment: I've updated - as noted no change to solution with change to input data.  logic is sound :-)